# TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteoric

I am using autoform in my project and getting this error when I open the form
Not sure if this is because of any versions or dependency, my autoform is not working and I am getting this error, I have the screenshot and the schema code, form code below,

[image]

**template**

```
<template name="assesmentNew">
  {{#ionModal customTemplate=true}}
    {{# autoForm collection="Assesments" id="assesments-new-form" type="insert"}}
      <div class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="button button-clear">Cancel</button>
        <h2 class="title">New Assesment</h2>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-positive button-clear">Save</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content has-header overflow-scroll">
        {{> afQuickField name="name" }}
        {{> afQuickField name="email"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="category"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="location"}}
      </div>
    {{/autoForm}}
  {{/ionModal}}
</template>
```

**Collection**

```
Assesments = new Mongo.Collection('assesments');
Assesments.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.createdAt = new Date();
});


Assesments.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
   type: String,
    label: 'First Name',
    autoform: {
      'label-type': 'floating',
      placeholder: 'First Name'
    }
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Email',
    autoform: {
      'label-type': 'floating',
      placeholder: 'Email'
  }
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
      label: 'Category',
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      options: [
        {value: 'General', label: 'General'},
        {value: 'Reported', label: 'Reported'},
        {value: 'Follow Up', label: 'Follow Up'}
      ],
      type: 'select-radio'
    }
  },
 assesmentDate: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Assesment Date',
    optional: true
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
      label: 'Location',
      autoform: {
      'label-type': 'floating',
      placeholder: 'Location'
    },
    max: 200
  },
 createdBy: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
    return this.userId
  }
}
  }
    ));

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Assesments.allow({ 
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
    },
    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
      return true;
    },
    remove: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a issue with the new patch for autoform-ionic to the new versions of autoform.

Apparently some labels are skipped, some not (see [here](https://github.com/meteoric/autoform-ionic/blob/master/ionic.js#L21)). In order to fix that and avoid this error when your input type is not there (for example, `type = number`), all your schema fields that are being rendered by autoform must have a label-type option defined:

```
...
autoform: {
   'label-type': 'placeholder',
   placeholder: 'Linha'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, @Rafael Quintanilha , but for some reason the insert is not happening.

Comment: What if Im not using simpleschema and also have this error? Im using Meteoric though..

Comment: Sorry I'm new, where exactly do we put this object?