# Meteor Build for android: TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null error when I run the production built server

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, meteor

I have the following demo: https://github.com/pc-magas/pupAndroidDemo

And I try to build it for android. I have installed the androis SDK and set the correct enviromental parameters.

Then as Readme.md says I run the following commands:

```
meteor build ~/builds/ --server=192.168.30.137:3821
cd ~/builds
tar -xvf pup.tag.gz
cd bundle/program/server
npm install
cd ../
cp ^project_folder^/settings-development.json ~/builds/settings.json
env MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/tesedb" ROOT_URL="192.168.30.137:3821" PORT=3821 METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat ../settings.json)" node main.js
```

But the last one:

```
env MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/tesedb" ROOT_URL="192.168.30.137:3821" PORT=3821 METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat ../settings.json)" node main.js
```

Throws me the following error:

> /home/pcmagas/builds/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:391 }).run();    ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null
>       at packages/meteor.js:1234:19
>       at packages/meteor.js:1246:4
>       at packages/meteor.js:1393:3
>       at /home/pcmagas/builds/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:338:34
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/pcmagas/builds/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>       at /home/pcmagas/builds/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:158:5
>       at /home/pcmagas/builds/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:387:5
>       at Function.run (/home/pcmagas/builds/bundle/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
>       at /home/pcmagas/builds/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:386:11

I have also seen the: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858068/typeerror-cannot-read-property-slice-of-null)

But it does not help me at all.

## Edit 1:

My `settings.json` contains:

```
{
  "public": {},
  "private": {
    "MAIL_URL": "",
    "OAuth": {
      "facebook": {
        "appId": "^FACEBOOK app id^",
        "secret": "^facebook_secret^",
        "loginStyle": "popup"
      },
      "google": {
        "clientId": "^client_id^",
        "secret": "^client_sectet^",
        "loginStyle": "popup"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

* Values between `^` is replacement for the actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you set the `ROOT_URL` enviromental variable value. You must ensure that starts with **http://**

As seen in: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8124

Answer (score 1):

First, check that you did copy correct `settings.json` file.

Second, remove `env` at the start of the line. If you're using `sh`-compatible shell then you don't need it.

Comment: I copied the correct `settings.json` file and I di try without `env` still problem remains.